IK and walking animation behaves strange together
I’m trying to make foot ik for my character. Character has also walking animation from mixamo. I’m giving weights (SetIKRotWeight, SetIKPosWeight) by using animation curves. If walking animation shows that one of feet is touching ground, curve that has variable for that foot goes one. Otherwise it goes zero. But knees are behaving strangly. They are twisting left and right while curve is reaching to 1.
I searched for google, chat gpt and youtube but I couldn’t notice anything. I appriciate so much if you could help.
